# Nodejs install adonis-framework get error

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

when i try to create simple project as adonis new awesome-project i get error:

```
adonis new awesome-project

Cloning into 'awesome-project'...
cleaning project
setting up app key
Fixing ace file
installing dependencies may take a while
installing dependencies... |
> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /home/mahdi/Desktop/Home/www/adonisjs/awesome-project/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

installing dependencies... | ERR! Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
installing dependencies... /
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mahdi/Desktop/Home/www/adonisjs/awesome-project/npm-debug.log
undefined
mahdi@HP-EliteBook:/var/www/adonisjs$
```

My linux operating system is `ubuntu` and i'm familiar `nodejs`, i don't have any problem for work with that

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: @l0rin `nodejs` version is v4.5.0 and `npm` version is 2.15.9

Comment: From the adonis documentation:
Node.js version 4.0 or greater.
npm version 3.0 or greater. try `npm i -g npm`

Comment: @l0rin Thanks its resolved, now i get this error: `npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: Please try to delete your node_modules folder, then run pm install again.

Comment: @l0rin i got the same error, i dont know whats error and i cant find any solution for that

Comment: @l0rin `fsevents` is for mac os, whats equivalent of that on linux?

Comment: fsevents should be an optional dependency, there could be an issue with the dependencies

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, I solved it by installing npm@3.8.9 (`npm install -g npm@3.8.9`)

Comment: @l0rin and could you create project with this command `adonis new awesome-project` ???

Comment: @l0rin Oh yeah sir, thank you very much, problem resolved, please reply to my post and let me to accept and upvote that

Comment: Yes with npm @ version 3.8.9 this was possible. There seems to be an issue with npm itself. Related links: https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/161 / https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the adonis documentation: Node.js version 4.0 or greater. npm version 3.0 or greater.

You have to upgrade your npm version to **3.8.9** in order to solve the problem. (`npm install -g npm@3.8.9`)

With any version higher there seems to be issue the same issue.

Related links: https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-framework/issues/161 / https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12647